# Strange margin in stack/row

Tags: flutter

I am getting this strange margin in the top of container who is in the stack.
I didn't manage to remove it in any way.

I made Pad reproducing my problem: https://dartpad.dev/3cff37d88cb391d15ffa13db818d5408

[image]

Comment: Why not just add `1` on to the calculated height? For example, change `final stripesHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2;` to `final stripesHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 + 1;`

Comment: I don't get that on DartPad

Comment: @LucaNeri yes, I know, it is working in that way, but this is like a hack, it is not supposed to work like this. Maybe I can report as an issue then.

Comment: @FederickJonathan Apparently, it depends on screen size. If you try changing the size of the web browser you will see a bug.